# Clang with Xcode 4 error: invalide option nodistribute

Tags: xcode4, static-analysis, clang

I have been trying to get clang's analysis tool working, but I am not sure how to overcome a particular error when I run it.  I have installed X-Code 4.0 and iOS 5 the output I get is:

---

### Generating class dependency graph.

Launching /Users//Desktop/HomeWork2/tools/AnalysisTool.app/Contents/Resources/llvm/utils/scan-build with arguments: (

```
"-o",
"/Users/<homedir>/Development/myApp/Static analysis/results",
"-v",
"--status-bugs",
"-checker-cfref",
"-warn-dead-stores",
"-warn-objc-methodsigs",
"-warn-objc-missing-dealloc",
"-warn-objc-unused-ivars",
"-analysistool-checker-access-control",
"-analysistool-checker-coersions",
"-analysistool-checker-cyclomatic-complexity",
"-analysistool-checker-conditional-logical-complexity",
"-analysistool-checker-conditional-nesting-depth",
"-analysistool-checker-loop-nesting-depth",
"-analysistool-checker-dealloc-safety",
"-analysistool-checker-declaration-conventions",
"-analysistool-checker-discouraged-method-calls",
"-analysistool-checker-error-handling",
"-analysistool-checker-extra-parentheses",
"-analysistool-checker-finalize",
"-analysistool-checker-format-strings",
"-analysistool-checker-kvo",
"-analysistool-checker-memory-management",
"-analysistool-checker-naming-conventions",
"-analysistool-checker-shadow",
"-analysistool-checker-unused-ivars",
"--use-cc=/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2",
"--use-c++=/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2",
"-generate-class-dependency-graph",
xcodebuild,
"CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/<homedir>/Development/myApp/Static analysis/build",
"CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR=/Users/<homedir>/Development/myApp/Static analysis/build",
"-configuration",
Debug,
clean,
build
```

).

scan-build: Emitting reports for this run to '/Users//Development/AMMO_SVN_Projects/MobXpo/branches/MobXpo_v12/Static analysis/results/2011-06-30-8'.

scan-build: 'clang-cc' executable not found in '/Users//Desktop/SWEN_646/HW2/tools/AnalysisTool.app/Contents/Resources/llvm/utils/libexec'.

scan-build: Using 'clang-cc' from path.

xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-nodistribute'

Usage: xcodebuild [-project ] [[-target ]...|-alltargets] [-configuration ] [-arch ]... [-sdk [|]] [=]... []...
       xcodebuild -workspace  -scheme  [-configuration ] [-arch ]... [-sdk [|]] [=]... []...
       xcodebuild -version [-sdk [|] [] ]
       xcodebuild -list [[-project ]|[-workspace ]]
       xcodebuild -showsdks

Options:

```
-usage                print full usage
-verbose              provide additional status output
-project NAME         build the project NAME
-target NAME          build the target NAME
-alltargets           build all targets
-workspace NAME       build the workspace NAME
-scheme NAME          build the scheme NAME
-configuration NAME   use the build configuration NAME for building each target
-xcconfig PATH        apply the build settings defined in the file at PATH as overrides
-arch ARCH            build each target for the architecture ARCH; this will override architectures defined in the project
-sdk SDK              use SDK as the name or path of the base SDK when building the project
-parallelizeTargets   build independent targets in parallel
-jobs NUMBER          specify the maximum number of concurrent build operations
-showsdks             display a compact list of the installed SDKs
-list                 lists the targets and configurations in a project, or the schemes in a workspace
-find BINARY          display the full path to BINARY in the provided SDK
-version              display the version of Xcode; with -sdk will display info about one or all installed SDKs
```

---

I have researched the internet but I have found nothing to help my specific problem. I think what i need to do is edit the clang tool to not include the "nodistribute" option, but im not sure if there is another way or where to get the source code to do so. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd suggest sending an email to the cfe-dev mailing list (http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev); you're much more likely to get an answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way around this after a lot of looking for an answer I decided to see if I could modify the line of code that was including the `-nodistribute` option.  So I used grep to find the line of code in the .app bundle and then opened it in vi.  I added a comment # to the line and bingo, off to the races.

The file, relative to the app bundle root is found at: `./Resources/llvm/utils/scan-build`